What is HEAD operation in CosmosDB reported in Azure Monitoring

This is AZ Monitoring showing the types of operations happening on CosmosDB. What is the Head operation reported 17.4K times in the above screenshot? I understand the operations Query, Create etc. I don't know what I am doing that results in Head operation and how can I reduce it. I couldn't find any public documentation about it.

the code comments here give one case where the SDK sends these requests (waiting for GlobalCommittedLsn to catch up after a write) https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/e645450e0ebed13eac3e2645be86b10cf73b4fb7/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/direct/ConsistencyWriter.cs#L28 I'm not sure of all the cases it happens

Personally I disagree that this is off topic - clearly this is a tool used by software developers and clarification of such product behaviours as how consistency levels are actually implemented is extremely useful. Not just a narrow focus on questions about syntax (and the fact that this product behaviour happens to be exposed through a graph in the portal rather than, say, running a query against a DMV doesn't make it off topic)

Collection Head requests are internal metadata requests which are used to provide the Strong consistency guarantees. These requests are not charged.
A transient increase in the number of collection head requests can happen when there is transient replication delay from the write region to the read region. These are usually resolved automatically.

It is also coming from Query operations that iterate over the results

Regarding "These requests are not charged" - I do see that when they are throttled they consume request units. - i.e. Total Requests metric shows head requests with both 204 and 429 status but “Total Requests Unit” metric only shows RU consumption for 429 status
